# Lookup on huge table is not happening sql-server

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql-server this is my query:

```
select asst_id,camp_asst.amp_asst_id,asst.camp_asst_id,lyty_no,campaign_id 
into camp.asst_respy 
from camp.asst_respy respy 
inner join camp.camp_wave wave on wave.wave_cd=resp.camp_id
inner join camp.camp_cust custy on cust.cust_lyty_no=resp.big_id
inner join camp.camp_asst assty on asst.sst_trck_url=resp.dum_url
inner join camp.camp_camp_assty camp_asst on camp_asst.camp_asst_id=asst.asst_id
inner join camp.camp_cust_assty cust_asst on cust_asst.camp_camp_asst_id=camp_asst.asst_id  -- this table has about 16 billion rows.
inner join camp.camp_camp_custy camp_cust on camp_cust.camp_camp_cust_id=cust_asst.cust_id
```

please somebody guide me in doing the join,the join is taking very long time. to happen
and there are indexes defined on table,I am looking to partition the table to make this happen please guide

remaining all tables used have about >10 Million rows.

Comment: Index defined on which column?

Comment: If you remove the table that has 16 billion rows, how many rows would the rest of the join have?  I would recommend joining everything that's not in the 16-billion table and caching the results in a heavily indexed temp (or temp-actual-table), then join your cached table onto the 16-billion table.

Comment: @MatthewBriggs: the remaining tables have about 10 Million rows

Comment: _General Advice_: start writing statement by joining only one table, and then two tables and so on.. identify tables which is causing the performance issue and identify index for that table first.

Comment: Given that you only need a handful of columns from those 10 Million rows I would still recommend caching the 10 Million join into a table with index, so that there is only one join statement touching the 16-billion.  However, 10 million onto 16-billion is going to take a while no matter what.  Can you narrow things down with a WHERE clause on the 16-billion?